# Porque no se guardan correctamente los datos? C

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer un vector con una estructura para al almacenar los datos se muestran de manera totalmente incorrecta y no tengo idea de porque. El programa se ejecuta bien (creo) pero falla en el almacenamiento y muestra de datos. Ni siquiera se muestra correctamente la palabra "si" y junta el dato del nombre con el dato de la edad

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct encuesta {
char nombre[4];
int edad;
char conoce[2];
char consume[2];
} tenc;
void datos(int j, tenc enc[]);

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Cantidad de encuestados\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    tenc e[n];
    datos(n, e);
    //--------------------------------------------------------//
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Nombre:%s\n",e[i].nombre);
    printf("Edad:%d\n",e[i].edad);
    printf("Conoce el producto:&s\n",e[i].conoce);
    printf("Consume el producto:%s\n",e[i].consume);
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
void datos(int j,tenc enc[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("\nNombre:");
        scanf("%s",&enc[i].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEdad:");
        scanf("%s",&enc[i].edad);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nConoce el producto?:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",&enc[i].conoce);
        printf("\nConsume el producto?:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",&enc[i].consume);
        printf("\n----------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
return;
}
```

LO QUE SALE AL EJECUTAR EL CODIGO ES ESTO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En

```
scanf("%s",&enc[i].edad);
```

tienes un %s y el dato es un entero por lo tanto tendrías que usar %d o %i

y en

```
printf("Conoce el producto:&s\n",e[i].conoce);
```

tienes un *&s* y es *%s*

Comment: arregle las cosas que me dijiste pero sigue sin funcionar